# How to check if EditText has a value in Android / Java

Tags: java, android

This should be simple, but I have tried if statements checking for null values and also ones checking the .length of it:

```
EditText marketValLow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.marketValLow);
EditText marketValHigh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.marketValHigh);
if (marketValLow.getText().length() != 0 && marketValHigh.getText().length() != 0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(v.getContext(), CurrentlyOwe.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(CurrentMarketValue.this, "You need to enter a high AND low.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

**But it doesn't detect nothing was entered. Any ideas?**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Please compare string value not with `==` but `equals()` :

```
String yourString = ;
if (marketValHigh.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
    // This should work!
}
```

Comment: As I said above: This works to stop progression to the next activity, but my toast does not show. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, my fault. Didn't add .show()!

Comment: Damn it! so why "==" is incorrect here?! :O

Comment: This is Java code, in Java, if you want to compare String content you use equals, if you want to compare their pointer, you use == (which is pretty rare.)

Comment: How about `marketValHigh.getText().length() != 0` ?

Answer (score 9):

This will check if the edit text is empty or not:

```
if (marketValLow.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
{
}
```

Comment: This works to stop progression to the next activity, but my toast does not show. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Toast.makeText(CurrentMarketValue.this, "You need to enter a high AND low.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

This will work.

Answer (score 2):

Rather what you can check is like:

```
String text = mSearchText.getText().toString();

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty( mSearchText.getText().trim())) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
String value = editText.getText().toString();
if (value == "")
{
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it stops progression to the next activity but doesn't show the toast there must be something wrong in your else statement. Have you read the Dev Guide article on Toast notifications? It is under User Interface -> Notifying the User -> Creating Toast Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Validation is somewhat tedious. Maybe I can help you in a more generic manner. I have written a basic framework to [validate fields in Android](http://dekwant.eu/?p=138).

It is totally free, and you can do whatever you like with it.

Answer (score 0):

write a simple function inside a class:

```
    public static boolean isEditTextEmpty( EditText et){
      String s = et.getText().toString();
      return s.equals("");  // really empty.          
   }

    public static boolean isEditTextInvisible( EditText et){
      String s = et.getText().toString();
      return s.trim().equals("");  // might have only spaces...           
   }
```

OR... with positive Logic:

```
    public static boolean hasContentEditText( EditText et){
      String s = et.getText().toString();
      return s != null; // spaces will count.             
   }
```